# ANSI C graphics extension

Tags: c, user-interface, frameworks

I have to make a project for the Windows OS in strics ANSI C (so im not allowed to use C++, C# or Objective-C). And I'm wondering if it is possible to use any kind of graphics. And if it's possible, how can I? Are there any open source frameworks for strict ANSI C that allow me to use GUI programming?

Thanks in advance,

Marnix van Rijswijk.

Comment: Wouldn't any "extension" by definition be non-standard?

Comment: @marnixvanrijswijk - I don't think that you (or the requestor) understand the question.  Strict ansi 'C' will 'never' have a GUI.  A line based interface like the old edlin maybe, but not a graphical front end. Just not in the scope of the language.  See Georg' answer below for good suggestions, noting that you will not be using ansi C as soon as you call an external API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are just not allowed to use any other C-derived language, not limited to only using the features plain ANSI-C gives you. Otherwise asking for frameworks doesn't make any sense - everything outside the standard-library would be off-limits for you.

If you are only targetting windows you can just use the [WinAPI](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/). Alternatively you could get a higher abstraction level and better portability by using toolkits like [gtk+](http://www.gtk.org/).

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, you totally answered my question. 

cheers!